# How to return songs from Apple Music API?

Tags: swift, rest, api, apple-musickit

I need add a new function that returns songs from Apple Music API. The code below returns nil however, it works for Album ID. I modified the code from APIClient.swift. See source for details.

It returns song(id:completion:) JSON Decode Failed.

Source: https://github.com/shingohry/AppleMusicSearch

SongModel.swift

```
func song(id: String, completion: @escaping (Resource?) -> Swift.Void) {
    let completionOnMain: (Resource?) -> Void = { resource in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            completion(resource)
        }
    }

    guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.music.apple.com/v1/catalog/\(APIClient.countryCode)/songs/\(id)") else { return }

    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    request.addValue("Bearer \(APIClient.developerToken)",
        forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

    data(with: request) { data, error -> Void in
        guard error == nil else {
            print(#function, "URL Session Task Failed", error!)
            completionOnMain(nil)
            return
        }

        guard let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!),
            let dictionary = jsonData as? [String: Any],
            let dataArray = dictionary["data"] as? [[String: Any]],
            let songDictionary = dataArray.first,
            let songData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: albumDictionary),
            let album = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Resource.self, from: songData) else {
                print(#function, "JSON Decode Failed");
                completionOnMain(nil)
                return
        }
        completionOnMain(song)
    }
}
```

Comment: does this returning any error in error block ?

Comment: song(id:completion:) JSON Decode Failed

Comment: try this `NSString(data: yourResponseData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)` n  print output of api call